# Power BI Incremental Refresh without Service

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need help with improving refresh times on a Power BI dashboard with about 20M rows of data and 80 columns pulling from SQL Server. I cannot use Power BI Service in any capacity, this has to load into Power BI Desktop.

My refresh times on the raw data (virtually no transformations in Power Query) are taking about 3-4 hours.

Microsoft recommends incremental refresh to archive my historical data and only refresh the latest changes, but that requires Service and I 100% cannot use it.

Is there any other way to significantly improve my refresh times beyond Service's incremental refresh? If it was under an hour I'd be happy.

What I've tried:

- Native Query to leverage the server
- reducing column selections
- removing all transformations
- Splitting tables in Power Query and selectively turning off refresh in the historical tables - as soon as they get stacked/appended Power Query triggers a refresh on all stacked tables regardless of which ones have refresh turned off.
- Looked into Power Query PQFL/M code to activate refresh of tables - can't find any method/property to control this in M code.
- optimizing the SQL, haven't gotten any significant improvements.

Comment: Does your **PBI dashboard** really need to have 1.6G of data points import-loaded, especially considering that you have a SQL server backend available, and you know how to query-fold? What's the use case for having all this data in a PBIX-file-constrained tabular model, especially one not pipelined to a wider audience via PBI Service?

Comment: In my case, yes, that is the requirement. The use case environment for this dashboard is extremely constrained with limited network connectivity. Even though SQL Server is available, the users can't realistically hit it with requests all the time so I need to have as much data as possible loaded into the PBIX to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

20 million rows should not take that long, especially with no transformations. Something else is going wrong but without access to your data and hardware, it is impossible to say.

One possibility is do an initial data load and then turn off refresh on that query. Add a new query for just the new data (which should be quick) but load the new query to a completely new table. In PBI, you will then have two tables. Create a calculated table in DAX which is a union of your old, non-refreshed data and your new data. Refreshes should be very quick after your first load but obviously you need to think about how it scales as your data grows.